# The intersection points of $m$ balls in $\mathbf{R}^n$

Tags: geometry

In $\mathbf{R}^n$ , balls of radii $R_1...R_m$ centered at $A_1...A_m$ have a common point . Prove that if $B_1...B_m$ are points such that $|B_iB_j|\le|A_iA_j|$ , then the balls of radii $R_1...R_m$ centered at $B_1...B_m$ also have a common point .

Answer (score -1):

Consider any of the two circles, suppose the one centered at $B_i$ with radius $R_i$ and that at $B_j$ with radius $R_j$. Name them $b_1$ and $b_2$. Translate the point $A_i$ to $B_i$ and rotate the line $A_iA_j$ so that it coincides with $B_iB_j$. Then it becomes obvious that $b_1$ and $b_2$ has a common point. As we have shown this for any two circles, the result follows.

Comment: A minor point. We are in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We may have $n>2$. But more seriously, we have to show that a single point belongs to all the $B_i$ (and we are given that a single point belongs to all the $A_i$). I do not think your argument is enough. (Consider the case where $A_j$ is inside $A_j$ and $R_i<R_j$. Moving $A_j$ closer to $A_i$ might take the point which worked for the $A_i$ system outside of $A_j$.)

Comment: When we move $A_j$ closer to $A_i$, the distance $A_iA_j$ does become smaller, but the distance to some other point may be larger. It is a problem from $Geometry$ by Prasolov and Tikhomirov, but there's something wrong with the solution they gave.Thanks for your help.